# FRAME access data

Tags: c#, html, iframe, webbrowser-control

I have next frame :

```
<FRAMESET BORDER="0" ROWS="100,500,130">
<FRAMESET BORDER="0" COLS="80%,20%">
    <FRAME SRC="http://aplinfo.apl.com/ext_html/hpttopnav.html" NAME="topframeOne" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 SCROLLING="no" NORESIZE>
    <FRAME SRC="/gentrack/blank.html" NAME="topframeTwo" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 SCROLLING="no" NORESIZE>

</FRAMESET>

<FRAMESET BORDER="0" COLS="16%,*,1%">
    <FRAME SRC="http://aplinfo.apl.com/cgi-bin/menutracking.pl?trackInput01=TEMU6460061&trackInput02=null&trackInput03=null&trackInput04=null&trackInput05=null&trackInput06=null&trackInput07=null&trackInput08=null" NAME="leftframe" NORESIZE>
    <FRAME SRC="/gentrack/containerTrackingFrame.do" NAME="bodyframe" NORESIZE>
    <FRAME SRC="/gentrack/blank.html" NAME="bottomframeTwo" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 NORESIZE>
</FRAMESET>


<FRAMESET BORDER="0" COLS="80%,*">
    <FRAME SRC="http://aplinfo.apl.com/ssi/ssifooterw.html" NAME="bottomframeOne" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 NORESIZE>
    <FRAME SRC="/gentrack/blank.html" NAME="bottomframeTwo" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 NORESIZE>
</FRAMESET>
```

Website: http://homeport.apl.com/gentrack/trackingMain.do?trackInput01=TEMU6460061

How I can access data in FRAME?

I tried this:

```
  html = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
  html = webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
```

For me it's not important is it from `WebBrowser` I just need read html/source of `FRAME` in C#.